# How to make certain URL's not work (even if the page exists)

Tags: php

For example, I have a page called `profile_page.php`. This page is only functional if data is written after the `?u=` in the URL, for example, data for Alice's profile page can only be seen when the URL reads `http://localhost/profile_page/alice`.

Loading `http://localhost/profile_page` will give me undefined variable errors as most of my variable's are depending on the URL to have a value after the `?u=`. For example, the variable `$firstname` can only be gathered when I get her username in the URL.

In such a case, when `http://localhost/profile_page`, I would rather have it redirect the user to their own `profile_page`, but I don't know how I can test the URL and parse it through an if statement.

I understand you can use `$u=$_GET['u'];` to obtain the current page URL? but I don't think doing this, is the best way to go about it:

```
$u=$_GET['u'];
if ($u == "http://localhost/profile_page/"){
// redirect to logged in users page code here
}
```

Comment: Are you using an .htaccess (or similar) file to do URL rewriting?

Comment: `if (!isset($_GET['u'])) die();`...!?

Comment: @kojow7 - Yes, I have an .HTACCESS file.

Comment: How is `u` the entire URL?  Where are there *any* query string parameters in the example you show?  It's not really clear what you're trying to do here.  If you're just checking whether or not a query string parameter is present, what's wrong with `isset()`?

Comment: @Freddy Are you using it to do URL rewriting?

Comment: @kojow7, Yes, I have URL rewriting completed for `profile_page.php` to allow users to type any valid users username after the `/` and get to their profile page.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are using some parameter for your page to build, the url would looks like `httlp://localhost/profile_page.php?firstname=alice&lastname=brown`, with `$_GET['firstname']` you will get `alice` in this case. If you want to test if the parameter is set first and redirect to another page if it is not set, you could use

```
if(!isset($_GET['firstname'])
{
   header('Location:redirected_page.php');
}
```